# Save 0 as a string in database using sqlite in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am inserting `@"0123"` as a string into a database using sqlite but it removes the `0` from the string and saves only `@"123"`.

**How can I save `@"0123"` in database?**

Comment: Use core data and store it as a string. Done.

Comment: Check datatype of column in your database, it should not be number

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF8String encoding to save text into sqlite DB.

Example :

```
NSString * yourString = @"0123";

sqlite3_bind_text(thumbAddStmt, 1, [yourString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```